# select skip and limit item array

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
user {
        [
            _id: xyz...,
            Statuss["id1", "id2", "id3", "id4", "id5", "id6", "id7", "id8", "id9", "id10"]
        ]
    }
```

I want to select `Statuss`  `skip(0).limit(5)`

Tried:

```
collection.findOne({_id: id}, {Statuss: {$slice: [0, 5]}
```

but the result is:

```
Statuss["id1", "id2", "id3", "id4", "id5"]
```

want this result:

```
Statuss["id10", "id9", "id8", "id7", "id6"]
```

Comment: I do word: collection.findOne({_id: id}, {Statuss: {$slice: [0, 5]} but the results: Statuss["id1", "id2", "id3", "id4", "id5"]

Answer (score 0):

Tried this:

```
collection.findOne({_id: id}, {Statuss: {$slice: [5, 5]}
```

Comment: I do not know leng of Statuss

Comment: what do you exactly want to achieve? too vague to answer.

Comment: every time I get 5 item latest